# Pentaho, Interactive Report- Disable Get Started Dialog & Tips

Tags: pentaho

Do anyone know how to disable the Dialog screen that starts when a new Interactive report is opened?

I found an article for disabling the welcome home perspective widgets but not the Interactive report welcome screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is you image, take a look into right bottom corner of screen )))

[image]